# Query Performance When Dropping Multiple Columns

Tags: postgresql, performance, alter-table, query-performance

In PostgreSQL, is there any performance gain when using a single `ALTER TABLE` statement to drop multiple columns, instead of using a separate statement to drop each column?

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1, DROP COLUMN col2, DROP COLUMN 3;

// vs

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1;
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col2;
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col3;
```

Comment: I put this question here because it is about query-performance, a topic covered by this site. If it belongs to SO please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it's too small to be noticed unless you plan to drop hundreds or even thousands of columns ;)

Each `drop column` is executed separately regardless if it's a separate statement, or part of a statement. The performance gain would be in the work postgres do before and after each statement, for instance taking a lock on the table, creating implicit transactions, and parsing the statement which it would only have to do once if all columns are dropped in one statement.